NeoDash - Add nodes with and without geo coordinates
Is there a way to visualize a node on a NeoDash map that doesn't have itself geo coordinates (red node on image), but that is connected to a node with geo coordinates (grey nodes below) ?
Currently such node is just ignored on the map.

